# Symfony widget clear label programmatically on render

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I am trying to programmatically set the label value of a widget after performing some checks but my below attempts are not working. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Note that the label already has a value and I just want to clear it. That is in symfony 1.4.

```
class customFormSome extends sfWidgetFormTextarea {

/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @see sfWidgetFormTextarea
 * */
protected function configure($options = array(), $attributes = array()) {        
    $this->addOption('element_id');
}

/**
 * @param  string $name        The element name
 * @param  string $value       The value displayed in this widget
 * @param  array  $attributes  An array of HTML attributes to be merged with the default HTML attributes
 * @param  array  $errors      An array of errors for the field
 *
 * @see sfWidget
 * */
public function render($name, $value = null, $attributes = array(), $errors = array()) {

   /*** SOME PROCESSING HERE******/

   $this->setAttribute('label', '');  //---->DOESNT WORK
   $this->setAttribute('label', FALSE);  //---->DOESNT WORK
   $this->setAttribute('label', NULL);  //---->DOESNT WORK
   $fields = $this->parent->setLabel($this->getOption('element_id'), '');//---->DOESNT WORK
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's too late to call `setAttiribute()` in render method, it gets attributes from `$attributes` parameter, so you only need to overwrite it:

```
public function render($name, $value = null, $attributes = array(), $errors = array()) {

   /*** SOME PROCESSING HERE******/

  $attributes['label'] = $this->getOption('element_id');
  return parent::render($name, $value, $attributes, $errors);
}
```